# Having titles stay with text

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Hello I am writing a fictional story in latex and i'm having trouble with dialogue boxes. When a character says something their name and dialogue are put together in a borderless box. However i am having trouble keeping the names and their corresponding dialogue together. The issue that is arising is presented in image below at the transition between page one an page two:

[image]

I want the name at the bottom of the page one to stick with the dialogue on the top of the page two.
The code i used to generate this is given below. It's the new environment called "dial" that i am having issue with.

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{article}

%used to make margins one left and right side of text
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 


%Used to create the dialogue boxes
\newenvironment{dial}[1]
    {
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{0.3cm}
            \normalsize{\textbf{#1\\[1ex]}}
            \begin{small}
                \begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm}

    }
    {

                \end{changemargin}
            \end{small}
        \end{center}
    }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{dial}{Abbott}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Costello}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Abbott}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Costello}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Abbott}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Costello}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Abbott}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Costello}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Abbott}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Costello}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Abbott}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Costello}
This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here. This is the Problem right here.
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Abbott}
hey
\end{dial}


\begin{dial}{Costello}
hey
\end{dial}


\end{document}



    \begin{dial}{Costello}
    hey
    \end{dial}


    \end{document}
```

I hope this is enough information to convey my issue. Bye and hope to here from you awesomnauts soon :D

Comment: `envcountsame` and `envcountschap` are strange options ;-)

Comment: You introduce _so_ many break points in that code it is not surprising that  you get a break! Latex has lots of commands for headings and itemised lists, all of which take care to control page breaking after a heading. (here you have uses a list but with an empty item (`\item[]`)

Comment: Perhaps the `dramatist` package is more of use here?

Comment: `\normalsize` is not a command with argument; make `\begin{small}` into `\small` and remove `\end{small}`; it should be `\textbf{#1}\\[1ex]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `\nopagebreak` to your environment between heading and content:

```
\newenvironment{dial}[1]
    {
        \begin{center}
            \vspace{0.3cm}
            \normalsize{\textbf{#1\\[1ex]}}
            \nopagebreak
            \begin{small}
                \begin{changemargin}{2cm}{2cm}

    }
    {

                \end{changemargin}
            \end{small}
        \end{center}
    }
```

While this solution should work flawlessly, note that your way of doing this may be not the best, remarkable alternatives are mentioned in the comments to your question.

Comment: SOMEBODY GET THIS GUY A SANDWICH! your awesome thanks for the super speedy help :D

Comment: @StevenDawson You're welcome. Adding a MWE always makes it really easy to help. ;)